# Solaris 11.1 x86 installing Weblogic 12.11

Tags: linux, installation, unix, java, solaris

Ive been looking everywhere for a way to install Weblogic on Solaris. According to Oracle's documentation, all you need to install Weblogic Graphical Mode is

- Login on Unix
- Go to the directory that contains the installation program.
- Launch the installation by entering the following command:

  ```
  -chmod a+x file_name.bin ./file_name.bin
  ```

So, this are my file attributes

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dbncourt staff    850362368 Jul 22 23:29 wls1211_linux32.bin
```

So i go and type:

```
chmod a+x wls1211_linux32.bin ./wls1211_linux32.bin
```

and absolutely nothing happens, and it says in the oracle's documentation that the window should appear. Then i go and try to open it in console mode since it said that if your console doesnt support "i dont remember what" the window wont show.

```
chmod a+x wls1211_linux32.bin ./wls1211_linux32.bin -mode=console
```

according to the documentation, that should do it. And i get this error

```
chmod: WARNING: can't access --
chmod: WARNING: can't access -mode=console
```

I know this is maybe a stupid question, but ive been trying for a while now with no result.
Is my very first time working with Solaris and Weblogic.

What im i doing wrong?¿ Im i lacking some package? is it the wrong wls to install?

BTW: I downloaded this wls because there was 3 options, Linux (.bin), Windows (.exe) and MacOs (.jar). And according to the documentation, to install on Unix platform using Graphical Mode, i need the .bin file.

Also im not runing root because they say you should not.

Srry for my English btw^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are separate commands you need to enter separately:

```
chmod a+x file_name.bin
./file_name.bin
```

The first changes the permission on file_name.bin to make it executable, the second runs that program.  Entering them as one command just causes the file permissions to be changed twice as both `file_name.bin` and `./file_name.bin` would be used as arguments to the chmod command.

Comment: Thx man!! now i get this error Cannot find /lib/ld-linux.so.2. Any idea what that means? cant find any answer about that too. Maybe its soooo basic and thats why theres almost no info about it or im just not using the right terms.

Comment: @dbncourt: You cannot find ld-linux.so.2 on Solaris, because Solaris is *not* Linux.  You need to download and install the Solaris version of Weblogic, not the Linux one.

Comment: Theres no Solaris or Unix version... Thx anyway!